# How to tell whether GNU make is being used in a makefile?

Tags: gnu-make

I know GNU Make is by far the most commonly used, but I'm looking for a way to verify that GNU Make is the actual make program that is being used.  Is there a special variable I can print from within the Makefile like:

```
@echo "$(MAKE_VERSION)"
```

What if I have both GNU Make and another variant installed?

```
which make
/usr/bin/make
```

Comment: On the terminal, Hit `make --version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using:

```
$(MAKE) --version
```

works here. My output is:

```
make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: This may well result in an error on systems where `make` is not GNU `make`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names):

> By default, when make looks for the makefile, it tries the following names, in order: GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile.

So if you name your make file `GNUmakefile`, then you should be guaranteed that it will only be read by GNU make and not by any other make.

Answer (score 3):

from [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2006-04/msg00065.html) the only way I found doing that into a makefile is

```
  ifeq (3.81,$(firstword $(sort $(MAKE_VERSION) 3.81)))
    # stuff that requires make-3.81 or higher
  endif
```

Comment: This requires GNU `make` to actually perform the test, does it not?

Comment: it takes the MAKE_VERSION variable from https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Quick-Reference.html